# javascript Wont add items from textbox

Tags: javascript, html

The problem is that the javascript will not run when i press the button on the form. i have no idea why its really annoying me, i am trying to make this add items via different text boxes then fining the average.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getmark() {
  var g1 = document.getElementById('g1').value;
  var g2 = document.getElementById('g2').value;
  var g3 = document.getElementById('g3').value; 
  var newtotal = total /3;

  var total = q1+q2+q3;

  alert(total);
}
</script>
```

it just doesn't seem to work for the life of me.

This is form im using to run it.

```
<form name = "gradecalc">
<p>Grade 1: Earned Points <input id='g1' type = "text"/> Out of:<input type = "text" value="9" readonly="readonly"/></p>
<p>Grade 2: Earned Points <input id='g2' type = "text"/> Out of:<input type = "text" value="9" readonly="readonly"/></p>
<p>Grade 3: Earned Points <input id='g3' type = "text"/> Out of:<input type = "text" value="9" readonly="readonly"/></p>
<p>Grade 6: Earned Points <input id='g6' type = "text"/> Out of:<input type = "text" value="9" 
<input id='entry_avg' onclick = "getmark()" type="button" value="Get Mark"/>
<input name = "clear" type = "reset" value = "Clear Form"/>
</form>
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you have invalid html, and never close your input tag.  On top of that, you define `g1` but not `q1`.  Lastly, you're concating strings.  You must convert them to a number.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error.

Comment: seems that: `total = q1+q2+q3;` is `total = g1+g2+g3;`, however `g1`,`g2` and `g3` are strings not numbers you must convert it... ex. `parseInt(g1)`

Comment: @Frogmouth I already said all of that.

Comment: True. I specified. if you see i have voted your answer... if it's not welcome... i'm sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

### What was the problem?

You had an unclosed tag and invalid Javascript

### How do I fix the problem?

Use this HTML:

```
<form name="gradecalc">
    <p>Grade 1: Earned Points
        <input id='g1' type="text" />Out of:
        <input type="text" value="9" readonly="readonly" />
    </p>
    <p>Grade 2: Earned Points
        <input id='g2' type="text" />Out of:
        <input type="text" value="9" readonly="readonly" />
    </p>
    <p>Grade 3: Earned Points
        <input id='g3' type="text" />Out of:
        <input type="text" value="9" readonly="readonly" />
    </p>
    <p>Grade 6: Earned Points
        <input id='g6' type="text" />Out of:
        <input type="text" value="9"/> <input id='entry_avg' onclick="getmark()" type="button" value="Get Mark" />
    </p>
        <input name="clear" type="reset" value="Clear Form" />
    </form>
```

And this javascript:

```
document.getElementById('entry_avg').addEventListener('click', function() { getmark(); });
function getmark() {
    var g1 = document.getElementById('g1').value;
    var g2 = document.getElementById('g2').value;
    var g3 = document.getElementById('g3').value;
    var total = parseInt(g1) + parseInt(g2) + parseInt(g3);
    var newtotal = total / 3;

    alert(total);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nQ238/5/)**

Comment: `$q != $g;` and `var total` came before `var newtotal` (I don`t downvote you)

Comment: please show this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nQ238/1/) - Change this too: This `var total = parseInt(g1) + parseInt(g2) + parseInt(g3);` came before `var newtotal = total / 3;` and then `alert(newtotal)`

Comment: `newTotal` has to be below `total`

Comment: I think it is. Excellent Man of Snow. That is will to help

Comment: Nop! And last but not least: `alert(newtotal);`

Comment: Right. I just hope user3163633 takes advantage of this answer xD

Comment: As a note; I'm deleting my replies because they're no longer relevant.

Comment: If this was a *good* answer from the start, I wonder how many upvotes it would've got :)